# how to get the current year in Angular 1 using just {{ }}?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

In a fairly complicated angular web app, I need the dynamic year to show up in a footer that doesn't have a directive. Is there an angular way to do it using just `{{SomeDateFunction()}}`?

I've seen people say `{{Date.now() | date:'yyyy'}}`, which doesn't display anything. I've tried `{{new Date().getFullYear()}}` which breaks angular and the error says

> [Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [new Date().getFullYear()] starting at [Date().getFullYear(].](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=Date&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=5&p3=new%20Date().getFullYear()&p4=Date().getFullYear()

I don't want to link a scope from the root scope, or put this in a directive just for the year, this is exactly the kind of thing {{ }} expressions should be able to solve, and non-date related simple {{ }} expressions display just fine.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what angular expressions are for.  they don't execute arbitrary JavaScript, they bind to properties on `$scope`.  if you happen to have a property on `$scope` that is a function, they will execute that function.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

`Date` is a member of the `window` object. Angular expressions don't use `eval`, and therefore don't expose the `window` object to expressions. You'll need to look at `squiroid's` answer below for a legitimate solution.

Comment: I guess I was confusing expressions with functions, thanks for the insight.

Comment: $scope.year = new Date().getFullYear();

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to define the date object inside the controller onto the scope.

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

And then in view do

```
{{date| date:'yyyy'}}
```

Comment: it's not what I wanted to hear, but thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: i did it like you but my attribute was declared only: date = new Date(); for Angular 9

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty late to response and hopefully you have already got the answer. Giving the answer for everybody's sake, -

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller('dateController', function($scope) {
    $scope.SomeDateFunction = function() {
      var currentdate = new Date();
      return currentdate.getFullYear();
    }
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.4" data-semver="1.6.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="dateController">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1> &copy; this is copyright protected as of {{SomeDateFunction()}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

it should get you what you want.